# Do i have to create folders for new domain names?

Tags: domain, domain-name, cpanel, nameserver

I already have a hosting server with an existing name-server.

I just purchased 3 domain names from a different vendor and supplied them with the correct name servers.

Do I have to create the necessary folders manually on my server or will they be created automatically?  If I am to create them manually, where in cPanel do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into cpanel control panel, the Domains section and choose Add-on domain.

When you provide the name of the domain, it will automatically suggest a name of the folder (based on the domain) and its location.  If you are happy with the choice, then tell it to go ahead and you are done.

Comment: do i perform this step before or after the domain transfer.

Comment: The domain transfer isn't important.  As long as the domain has the right nameservers, it doesn't matter who the registrar is.  However, you can perform this process at any time.